# Displaying user data fields from a firestore document in a flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to flutter and firebase/firestore, and I'm designing my first app.

I wrote this method in order to get the document of the currently logged in user from firestore:

```
getPatientData() async {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      .doc('PatientData')
      .collection('Patients')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
}
```

and I have this very basic ListView filled with TextFormFields that I want to fill with the fields from the user record:

```
ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Full Name',
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:
                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Email',
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:
                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Password',
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:
                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Phone Number',
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:
                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

But I don't know how I can access the fields within the doc I retrieved using the getUserData() method so I can display them in the TextFormFields.

Comment: Your `getPatientData` is not loading any document from Firestore yet. That won't happen until you call `get()`. I recommend having another look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart_1

Answer (score 0):

I designed auth function with 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'.
When customers login your application, you could use "User(firebase_auth)" to get the logined account information.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:trashcollectionday/utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
late User loggedInUser;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'chat_screen';

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final messageTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  late String messageText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async{
      try {
        final user = await _auth.currentUser!;
        if (user != null) {
          loggedInUser = user;
          // print(loggedInUser.email);
        }
      }
      catch(e) {
        print(e);
      }

  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                messagesStream();
                // _auth.signOut();
                // Navigator.pop(context);
                //Implement logout functionality
              }),
        ],
        title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            MessageStream(),
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageTextController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                        //Do something with the user input.
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageTextController.clear();
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add(
                        {
                          'text': messageText,
                          'sender': loggedInUser.email,
                        }
                      );
                      print("sent");

                      //Implement send functionality.
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```